# Sending Data between an iPhone and iPad?

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is it possible to use an iPhone to connect and send data to a iPad? And how would you go about doing this?

Could you open a socket and connect to the iPad with its IP address? (iPads/iPhones have an ip address right?) 
Go easy I'm new to network programming...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the "Bonjour" samples.  This will allow you to easily discover nearby (in a network sense) iPhone/iPad devices.

Comment: Presuming you are in Apple's developer program, it's one of their available examples.